# Вылет приложения при нажатии на VideoView

Tags: android, android-studio, videoview

Присваиваю видео:

```
VideoView vv = view.findViewById(R.id.vvVideoRecipe);
vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(7)));
vv.setMediaController(new MediaController(context));
vv.requestFocus(0);
vv.start();
```

Видео воспроизводится, все ок. Но при нажатии на него приложение вылетает с ошибкой `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`. В чем дело? VideoView располагается во фрагменте.